# Unit Test a function inside @Configuration - SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

I have added an x-correlation-id in request header inside the restTemplate function shown below. I want to write a unit test to verify if x-correlation-id is attached to the request header. I am not a Java developer and this is a one off task. Please help me unit test the part where "x-correlation-id" - X_CORRELATION_ID is in the request header

```
@Configuration
public class RestConfiguration {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestConfiguration.class);

    @Bean @Primary
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(
            CorrelationComponent correlationComponent,
            CloudTokener cloudTokener,
            @Value("${tokens.aad.role-app.resource}") String resourceId,
            RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder,
            @Value("${rest.connect-timeout}") Long connectTimeout,
            @Value("${rest.read-timeout}") Long readTimeout
    ) {
        log.trace("restTemplate() start");
        List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = Arrays.asList((request, body, execution) -> {
            // add correlation ID header
            
            request.getHeaders().set(Constants.X_CORRELATION_ID, correlationComponent.getCorrelationId());
            return execution.execute(request, body);
        });
        RestTemplate bean = restTemplateBuilder
                .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(connectTimeout))
                .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(readTimeout))
                .interceptors(interceptors)
                .build();
        log.trace("restTemplate() end");
        return bean;
    }
}
```

I know I am doing this wrong. Please help me write the correct unit test specifically in SpringBoot Java.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

class RestConfigurationTest {
    RestConfiguration restConfiguration;
    @Value("${tokens.abc.role-app.resource}") String resourceId;
    @Value("${rest.connect-timeout}") Long connectTimeout;
    @Value("${rest.read-timeout}") Long readTimeout;
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        restConfiguration = new RestConfiguration();
    }
    @Test
    public void testRestTemplate() {
        CorrelationComponent correlationComponent = mock(CorrelationComponent.class);
        CloudTokener cloudTokener = mock(CloudTokener.class);
        RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder = mock(RestTemplateBuilder.class);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = restConfiguration.restTemplate(correlationComponent,azureTokener, resourceId, restTemplateBuilder, connectTimeout, readTimeout );
        
    }
    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to test your configuration class. But if you really want to test it, you should test it by loading the context, but not using the mocking.

```
@SpringBootTest
@Import(RestConfiguration.class)
class RestConfigurationTest {

}
```

This will load your configuration class and test your values.